# How to register an articulated model to noisy predictions?

Tags: algorithms, graphics

[image: Sample scenario]

Given point sets $Y$ and $M$, I'd like to register articulated $M$ to $Y$ without changing the edge distances of $M$. The point correspondences between $Y$ and $M$ are known and points have a fixed connectivity map.

As you can see from the above sample, the edge distances of $Y$ are corrupted, and I'd like to correct them using $M$ while sacrificing some localization precision.

I know ICP (Iterative Closest Point) and RANSAC (Random Sample Consensus) algorithms, but none of them solve the articulation problem. I'm looking for any kind of algorithms that can solve this articulated body registration problem.

Comment: What does it mean to "register articulated M to Y without changing the edge distances of M"?  What do you mean by "the articulation problem"?  Can you provide a self-contained description of the problem statement?

Comment: Good question, any help would be appreciated.